# detect lua version to use [brew switch] conditionally for handling mismatched lua version usage per package

Tags: vim, lua, homebrew

vim8 uses version 5.2.x and another package uses 5.3.x of lua

right now i have set an alias for each package that switches the lua version using `brew switch lua 5.2.x / 5.3.x` depending on the package.

is there a better way of doing this? i primarily use vim so what id like to do is:

```
check the lua version being currently used 

  if it matches vim's version do nothing

  if it does not match vims version then `brew switch lua 5.2.x`
```

then on the other package(s) i can just use the alias.

this way i am not redundantly running the `brew switch` command for vim every time i call it